# PHP Post Variable

Tags: php, variables, post, form-post

How would i get the $frompage variable to send to the page it is posting to here is what i thought:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" />
<?php 
$frompage = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
echo '<form name="form1" method="post" action="report.php">';
echo "What is Wrong?";
echo '<textarea style="resize: none;" name="message" cols="70" rows="10" id="message">        </textarea>';
echo'<input type="hidden" name="$frompage" value="$frompage">';
echo '<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">';
echo "</form>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple, no need to echo all of the HTML.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" />
<form name="form1" method="post" action="report.php">
    <label>What is Wrong?</label>
    <textarea style="resize: none;" name="message" cols="70" rows="10" id="message">        </textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="frompage" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you change this line:

```
'<input type="hidden" name="$frompage" value="$frompage">'
```

into this:

```
'<input type="hidden" name="frompage" value="$frompage">'
```

when the user send the data, you can retrieve it using:

```
$_POST['frompage']
```

Answer (score 0):

First your using too much echos :P this is how I would do it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" />
<?php 
$frompage = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
?>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="report.php">
What is Wrong?
<textarea style="resize: none;" name="message" cols="70" rows="10" id="message">        </textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $frompage" ?> value="<?php echo $frompage" ?>>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When you use echo ''; The single quotes forces everything to be read exactly as it stated. If you REALLY wanted to echo all that html, use double quotes.
Such as echo "Hello $frompage";